# Java: Compressing the JPEG Image

Tags: java, image-processing, javax.imageio

I tried to compress the JPEG with the code I got from [codegeeks](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/compress-a-jpeg-file/)

Here is what I  implemented,

```
   public File compressJPEGImage(String filePath, float ratio) {

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
    ImageWriter jpegWriter = writers.next();

    // Set the compression quality to float value like 0.8
    ImageWriteParam param = jpegWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(ratio);

    // Write the image to a file
    File filepath = new File(filePath + "/" + imageModel.getId() + ".jpeg");
    FileImageOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileImageOutputStream(filepath);
        jpegWriter.setOutput(out);
        jpegWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
        jpegWriter.dispose();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error Compressingthe JPEG image" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return filepath;
}
```

when I wrote a test case to validate it. I got the following Exception, can anyone,fix this bug

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.initWriterIDs(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.initWriterIDs(Native Method)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.<clinit>(JPEGImageWriter.java:186)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance(JPEGImageWriterSpi.java:96)
at javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi.createWriterInstance(ImageWriterSpi.java:351)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:843)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageWriterIterator.next(ImageIO.java:827)
at com.quixey.media.service.converter.ImageConversion.compressJPEGImage(ImageConversion.java:111)
at com.quixey.media.service.converter.ImageConversionTest.test_CompressImage(ImageConversionTest.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
```

Comment: what JDK do you use?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you google for

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter.initWriterID`
```

you will find that this is a known bug in [Open JDK 8 versions](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1421501).

As a workaround you could use JDK 7, or try to switch to a later JDK 8 version.

Comment: I changed my java version to from openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"  to java version "1.8.0_45"  but it still shows the same error .

Comment: did you try a 1.7 version - just for the proof that it once worked.